# Reading UTF-8 from stdin using fgets() on Windows

Tags: c, powershell, winapi, utf-8

I'm trying to read a UTF-8 string from `stdin` using `fgets()`. The console input mode has been set to `CP_UTF8` before. I've also set the console font to Lucida Console in PowerShell. Finally, I've verified that UTF-8 output is working by printing a German `Ä` (in UTF-8: 0xC3,0x84) to the console using `printf()`. This is working correctly but `fgets()` doesn't seem to be able to read UTF-8 from the console. Here is a small test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned char s[64];

    memset(s, 0, 64);

    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);    
    SetConsoleCP(CP_UTF8);

    printf("UTF-8 Test: %c%c\n", 0xc3, 0x84);  // print Ä

    fgets(s, 64, stdin);

    printf("Result: %d %d\n", s[0], s[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

When running this program and entering "Ä" and then hitting ENTER, it just prints the following:

```
Result: 0 0
```

i.e. nothing has been written to `s`. When typing "A", however, I get the following correct result:

```
Result: 65 10
```

So how can I make `fgets()` work with UTF-8 characters on Windows please?

***EDIT***

Based on Barmak's explanations, I've now updated my code to use `wchar_t` functions instead of the ANSI ones. However, it still doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    wchar_t s[64];

    memset(s, 0, 64 * sizeof(wchar_t));

    _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U16TEXT);       
    fgetws(s, 64, stdin);

    wprintf(L"Result: %d\n", s[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

When entering `A` the program prints `Result: 3393` but I'd expect it to be `65`. When entering `Ä` the program prints `Result: 0` but I'd expect it to be `196`. What the heck is going on there? Why isn't even working for ASCII characters now? My old program using just `fgets()` worked correctly for ASCII characters like `A`, it only failed for non-ASCII characters like `Ä`. But the new version doesn't even work for ASCII characters or is `3393` the correct result for `A`? I'd expect it to be `65`. I'm pretty confused now... help please!

Comment: this is already your error - need use _O_WTEXT but not _O_U16TEXT

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't change anything. I still get 3393 for A and 0 for Ä on PowerShell 2.0 on Windows 7 and 3393 for A and 3470 for Ä on PowerShell 5.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: from my side all work

Comment: 0x41 for 'A' and 0xc4 for 'Ä'

Comment: and in any case - _O_U16TEXT is mistake, logic for _O_U16TEXT different from _O_WTEXT - you cannot got equal result with this 2 flags

Comment: Hmm, weird, I don't understand this. How did you compile the example I provided? Do I need to use any special defs? I just did a `cl test.c` , i.e. I didn't define `UNICODE` or `_UNICODE` or anything

Comment: i not compile your example exactly, but test with self code. i advice you first test with ReadConsoleW - this is low level func - must return correct values for 'A' (0x41) and 'Ä' (0xc4). if ok here, try fgetws, which internal call ReadConsoleW only in case _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_WTEXT) (with anode mode - ReadFile used, which get error by windows bug for not eglish chars)

Comment: Right, ReadConsoleW() works correctly and returns 0x41 for A and 0xc4 for Ä. So is fgetws() broken or what do you think?

Comment: sorry, i mistake - check _O_WTEXT and _O_U16TEXT work equivalent - in both case i got 0x41 for A and 0xc4 for Ä with fgetws

Comment: fgetws correct in my test

Comment: My version of VC is rather old (2012 or so). Maybe it was a bug in that version and has been fixed now? I can't think of any other explanation...

Comment: need look under debugger. or upload your test exe to file share and paste link here

Comment: Here's the exe and the source compiled using VC 15.00.30729.01 for x86:  http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=03063316761486264491

Comment: you use static libc library - and here also error in implementation. they even not import ReadConsoleW - but only this API can got correct result when not english charset used. always ReadFile used. and you got ANSI string in result - "I still get 3393 for A " - 3393=0x0D41 - this is 0x41+0x0d = 'A' + '\r' , 0 for Ä - i describe this windows bug. so try use not static but dynamic link - use from msvcrt.lib - i use import from msvcrt.dll - and this give me correct result

Comment: Right, using the dynamic one works fine so it's a bug in the static link library. Thanks a lot for all your efforts!

Comment: double bug - first bug in windows itself - in conhost.exe or conhostV2.dll(win10) which i describe in answer (incorrect buffer size in call WideCharToMultiByte) and second bug in concrete libc.lib - not used ReadConsoleW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All windows native string manipulations (with very rarely exceptions) was in UNICODE (UTF-16) - so we must use unicode functions anywhere. use ANSI variant - very bad practice. if you will be use unicode functions in your example - all will be work correct. with ANSI this not work by .. windows bug !
i can cover this with all details (researched on win 8.1):

1) in console server process exist 2 global variables:

```
UINT gInputCodePage, gOutputCodePage;
```

it can be read/write by GetConsoleCP/SetConsoleCP and GetConsoleOutputCP/SetConsoleOutputCP.
they used as first argument for WideCharToMultiByte/MultiByteToWideChar when need convert. if you use only unicode functions - they never used

2.a) when you write to console UNICODE text - it will be writen as is without any conversions. on server side this done in SB_DoSrvWriteConsole function. look picture:
[image]
2.b) when you write to console ANSI text - SB_DoSrvWriteConsole also will be called, but with one additional step - MultiByteToWideChar(gOutputCodePage, ...) - your text will be converted to UNICODE first. 
[image]
but here one moment. look:
[image]
in MultiByteToWideChar call cchWideChar == cbMultiByte. if we use only 'english' charset (chars < 0x80) length of UNICODE and multibyte strings in chars always equal, but with another languages - usual Multibyte version use more chars than UNICODE but here this is not problem, simply size of out buffer more then need, but it is ok. so you printf in general will be work correct. one note only - if you hardcode multibyte string in source code - faster of all it will be in CP_ACP form, and conversion to UNICODE with CP_UTF8 - give incorrect result. so this is depended in which format your source file saved on disk :)

3.a) when you read from console with UNICODE functions - you got exactly UNICODE text as is. here no any problem. if need - you can then direct by self convert it to multibyte

3.b) when you read from console with ANSI functions - server first convert UNICODE string to ANSI, and then return to you ANSI form. this done by function

```
int ConvertToOem(UINT CodePage /*=gInputCodePage*/, PCWSTR lpWideCharStr, int cchWideChar, PSTR lpMultiByteStr, int cbMultiByte)
{
    if (CodePage == g_OEMCP)
    {
        ULONG BytesInOemString;
        return 0 > RtlUnicodeToOemN(lpMultiByteStr, cbMultiByte, &BytesInOemString, lpWideCharStr, cchWideChar * sizeof(WCHAR)) ? 0 : BytesInOemString;
    }
    return WideCharToMultiByte(CodePage, 0, lpWideCharStr, cchWideChar, lpMultiByteStr, cbMultiByte, 0, 0);
}
```

but let look more close, how ConvertToOem called:
[image]
here again cbMultiByte == cchWideChar, but this is 100% bug ! multibyte string can be longer than UNICODE (in chars of course) . for example "Ä" - this is 1 UNICODE char and 2 UTF8 chars. as result WideCharToMultiByte
 return 0. (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER )

Comment: What disassembler are you using here? I haven't seen anything that inserts comments like that. Is it getting those from the Microsoft symbols, or are you typing those manually?

Comment: i use own debugger. this screenshots from it. and of course i use PDB symbols. green comments "// cbMultibytes*" - i add to screenshots later in mspaint :)

Comment: You've written your own debugger? That's hardcore! It's not open source, is it?

Comment: yes, this is world-class debugger, one of the best in world with many unique and power features(like partial live kernel debugging, debug protected process, function call tracing (tree view from it here), debug from first instruction in user mode, and many etc). this not open source but binary installation is exist

Comment: So are you saying that my `fgets()` approach *should* work but doesn't because there is a bug in Windows?

Comment: @Andreas - yes. windows bug. in call WideCharToMultiByte used not enough length buffer for multibyte string

Comment: but how i wrote - use ANSI functions - very bad practice. all already many years must use UNICODE version of functions.

Comment: Unfortunately, using `fgetws()` doesn't work either. See my edited post above. I've included new example code.

Answer (score 4):

Windows uses UTF16. Most likely Windows' console doesn't support UTF8.

Use UTF16 along with wide string functions (`wcsxxx` instead of `strxxx`). You can then use `WideCharToMultiByte` to convert UTF16 to UTF8. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <io.h> //for _setmode
#include <fcntl.h> //for _O_U16TEXT

int main()
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U16TEXT);
    wchar_t s[64];
    fgetws(s, 64, stdin);
    _putws(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you can't use ANSI print functions after calling `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT)`, it has to be reset. You may try something like the functions below which reset the text mode.

```
char* mygets(int wlen)
{
    //may require fflush here, see _setmode documentation
    int save = _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U16TEXT);
    wchar_t *wstr = malloc(wlen * sizeof(wchar_t));
    fgetws(wstr, wlen, stdin);

    //make UTF-8:
    int len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wstr, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    if (!len) return NULL;
    char* str = malloc(len);
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wstr, -1, str, len, 0, 0);
    free(wstr);

    _setmode(_fileno(stdin), save);
    return str;
}

void myputs(const char* str)
{
    //may require fflush here, see _setmode documentation
    int save = _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);

    //make UTF-16
    int wlen = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, str, -1, 0, 0);
    if (!wlen) return;
    wchar_t* wstr = malloc(wlen * sizeof(wchar_t));
    memset(wstr, 0, wlen * 2);
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, str, -1, wstr, wlen);

    _putws(wstr);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), save);
}

int main()
{
    char* utf8 = mygets(100);
    if (utf8)
    {
        myputs(utf8);
        free(utf8);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suspected that as well, but the strange thing is that `printf()` with an UTF-8 string actually does work (see my example above). It's just `fgets()` that doesn't seem to work...

Comment: I don't know why `SetConsoleCP(CP_UTF8)` behaves that way. Anyway, it's easy enough to make your own UTF-8 functions, see edit. It might be too much work just for Ä character. Is `setlocale` an option?

Comment: Unfortunately, using `fgetws()` doesn't work either. I've updated my original posting to include new example code based on your remarks. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: I had only tried that on English keyboard. What language are you using?

Comment: I changed the keyboard input to German on my computer, it still works as expected. Are you sure you didn't accidentally set keyboard input to some non-Latin language?

Comment: Yes, but maybe the problem is related to Windows 7 and PowerShell 2.0? I've now tested it on Windows 10 (in VMware) and PowerShell 5.0 and it doesn't return 0 there. When entering `Ä` in PowerShell 5.0 on Windows 10 the result is 3470. But I don't understand these character codes either. I still get 3393 for A and now 3470 for Ä. Shouldn't that be 65 for A and 193 for Ä in UTF-16?

Comment: `A` = `0x41`. And `3393` = `0xD41`, they look similar. It is AND with something else. I am not sure what is going on.